# Using 'contains' in an EL Expression

Tags: user-interface, oracle-adf

I want to set the inlineStyle property of a PanelGroupLayout programatically, but based on EL expression.

If an arrayList contains an ID, I would want to highlight it in Red color, else in Blue Color.

To accomplish this, I tried the following, but in vain.

```
    promptPGL.setInlineStyle((String)getValueExpression("#{backingBeanScope.OutlineBean.nodeSelectionTreeHierarchy.contains(" + currentLearningItemId + 
                                                        ")?'background-color:Lime;':'background-color:Gray;'}").getValue(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext()));
```

Any help is appreciated.